# Automatic image slider with setInterval function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Third photo of slider doesn't apper on slide. After a while slide fails completely, photos are changing rapidly. After the slide fail, when photos are changing rapidly, third photo appears sometimes. But I couldn't figure out why it doesn't appears at first and why slide is getting faster. How can I fix this problem?

```js
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
current = 0;

function reset() {
  for(let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

function startSlide() {
  reset();
  if(current == sliderImages.length) {
    current = 0;
  }  
  sliderImages[current].style.display = "block";
  current++;
  setInterval(startSlide, 2000);
}

startSlide();
```

```css
body, #slider, .wrap, .slide-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide1 {
  background-image:   url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3153198/pexels-photo-3153198.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260");
}

.slide2 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3153208/pexels-photo-3153208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260")
}

.slide3 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036641/pexels-photo-1036641.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260")
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slide-content">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slide-content">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide3">
      <div class="slide-content">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is everytime you run the function a new interval is going to be set, so you will end up with a bunch of them running at the same time. You just need to set it once, and then the function will be called every two seconds appropriately. I modified your example:

```js
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
current = 0;

function reset() {
  for(let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

function startSlide() {
  reset();
  if(current == sliderImages.length) {
    current = 0;
  }  
  sliderImages[current].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

setInterval(startSlide, 2000);
```

```css
body, #slider, .wrap, .slide-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide1 {
  background-image:   url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3153198/pexels-photo-3153198.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260");
}

.slide2 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3153208/pexels-photo-3153208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260")
}

.slide3 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036641/pexels-photo-1036641.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260")
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slide-content">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slide-content">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide3">
      <div class="slide-content">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```